# initial state in s domain

Tags: analog, circuit-analysis

in question below I couldn't' evaluate the initial state for inductors and capacitor in order to do the s domain analysis. If you can also show me how can I draw the circuit for inital state, I would be really greatful. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For initial conditions, assume the circuit is in a DC state. Thus inductors appear as shorts and capacitors are open. So Just treat the circuit as a resistive network at t=0.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So can you explain how should I treat the dependent source? Should ı cancel that side of the circuit? If that so how I can calculate the initial voltage of capacitor ?

Comment: I believe node A would be node B + 2ix. Remember is(0) is 0 amps since it is a unit function.